# Sync posts via JSON API

Tags: custom-post-types, api, sync

We have a custom post type Events on our Wordpress website. Every event has a title, description and date.

From our CRM-system, we can create a JSON feed where we list all Events. Every event in the feed will have a unique ID, title, description and date.

Now we want to set up a sync from the CRM > Wordpress system. In general:

- Automatically sync every x hours the data from CRM to Wordpress
- If an Event does not yet exist in Wordpress, but exists in CRM, then create the Event in Wordpress
- If an Event exists Wordpress and in CRM, then sync the Event data
- If an Event exists in Wordpress, but not in the JSON, then delete the event in Wordpress

Thank you.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here, sorry. How familiar are you with PHP programming in WordPress? You could add a [Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) which fetches the data and updates your CPT.

Comment: @kero The link to added in your comment lead to the WordPress built in cron scheduler, it doesn't fetches or updates data on its own, OP will need to build all this CRUD logic from the ground up, using WordPress REST API. I dont even think WordPress crons would work well in this case, as they trigger only when a user enters the site, if no user vistis the site the cron will not run, so better use the hosting cron.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast There is also a cahapter on [scheduling events](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/). (And turning off default behaviour that user triggers Cron should be a first thing to do, use real system Cron instead to trigger it.) In this approach I'd trigger a call each 1h or so, check the external DB and update WP. If the external system supports push (webhooks/similar), that would be a bit nicer of course.

Comment: you should edit out the plugin recommendation request, it will get your question closed ass off topic, recommendations are off topic here and not allowed. Use the edit link underneath the tags to update your question with more information and to remove the request for plugins

Comment: Thank you for your replies. If I understand well, the best way is to run a server Cron job fetching the JSON information and updating the wp_post and wp_postmeta table directly? Since we are working with custom post type, I think the risks are rather low of breaking things in the process.